# Preventing unauthorized logged users to edit/Delete in asp.net core

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity

I am trying to prevent unauthorized logged in users from seeing and editing other customers records but seem not working. I have asp.net core ApplicationUser tied to each category created. I am trying to match the currentUser Id and the applicationUser Id that is stored in the Database.

So if another user should put a category id in the URL that doesn't match with the currently logged ApplicationuserID. If that didn't match then redirects to index of category.

I don't know what I am doing wrong. I have tried different options and other suggestions online

```
// GET: Categories/Edit/5
        public async Task<IActionResult> Edit(int? id)
        {
            var currentUser = await _userManager.GetUserAsync(HttpContext.User);

            var Categories = _context.Categories.FirstOrDefault(m => m.ApplicationUserId == currentUser.Id);

            if (id == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }
            if (Categories.ApplicationUserId != currentUser.Id)
            {
                return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
                //return View(category);
            }
            else
            {
                var category = await _context.Categories.FindAsync(id);
                if (category == null)
                {
                    return NotFound();
                }
                return View(category);
            }
        }
```

The Httpedit

```
  [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Edit(int id, [Bind("CategoryId,StoreId,ApplicationUserId,CategoryName,Description")] Category category)
        {
            var currentUser = await _userManager.GetUserAsync(HttpContext.User);
            var store = _context.Stores.FirstOrDefault(m => m.ApplicationUserId == currentUser.Id);
            var categories = _context.Categories.FirstOrDefault(m => m.ApplicationUserId == currentUser.Id);

            if (id != category.CategoryId)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }
            if (categories.ApplicationUserId != currentUser.Id)
            {
                return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
            }
            else
            {
                if (ModelState.IsValid)
                {
                    try
                    {

                        category.StoreId = store.Id;
                        category.ApplicationUserId = currentUser.Id;
                        _context.Update(category);
                        await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
                    }
                    catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException)
                    {
                        if (!CategoryExists(category.CategoryId))
                        {
                            return NotFound();
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            throw;
                        }
                    }
                    return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
                }
            }
            return View(category);
        }
```

Thanks

Comment: What exactly isn't working? Is the `HttpContext.User` correct?  Have you tried adding the `[Authorize]` attribute as well?

Comment: I'm not sure I entirely understand what is going wrong?  Are users able to edit / delete other categories?

Comment: Yes, other logged in users are able to edit/delete categories. If I change the category id in the url, I am able to access other users categories. eg ``` /Categories/Edit/5```

Comment: Let me try `[Authorize]` on the edit/delete method

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to change the flow some (and avoid unnecessary database calls).

**Warning:** I edited this in place and have not tested it at all!

```
// GET: Categories/Edit/5
public async Task<IActionResult> Edit(int? id)
{
    // Fail early here, no reason to check the DB if 
    // the user doesn't include the right information
    if (id == null)
    {
        return NotFound();
    }

    var currentUser = await _userManager.GetUserAsync(HttpContext.User);

    // First, look up the category the user is attempting to access
    var category = await _context.Categories.FindAsync(id);

    // Check that the category the user is accessing belongs to them
    if (category.ApplicationUserId != currentUser.Id)
    {        
        return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
    }

    return View(category);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this actually work for me. This is what I have been looking for. Although I have not tried other mentions

Answer (score 0):

You check user's first category with this:

```
var Categories = _context
    .Categories.FirstOrDefault(m => m.ApplicationUserId == currentUser.Id);
```

This code returns false when check like this `categories.ApplicationUserId != currentUser.Id` because  IDs are equal. You should change your code like this

```
var Categories = _context
    .Categories.FirstOrDefault(m => m.CategoryId == id.Value)
```

After this change, `categories.ApplicationUserId` can be different from `currentUser.Id`

Comment: Please take the time to learn how to properly use markdown formatting in your contributions to SO.